# Headers Not Loading on Google Big Query Data Export

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to export a big query table to cloud storage and for some reason, I have header=true but no column headers are being added to my export file upon creation. I've deleted the file and re-tried several times with no luck. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
  EXPORT DATA
    OPTIONS ( uri = 'gs://data-feeds-public/inventory_used_google_merchant*.csv',
        format='csv',
        overwrite = true,
        header= true) 
        
        AS

     SELECT * FROM `mytable'
```

Comment: I have replicated this query with my sample dataset but it successfully adds a header when set to true. May I request a sample data for this ?

Comment: I have accessed the file from your query. It appears that it has headers already ?